# I want to load route first , after that i want to load the static files from public folder in node.js?

Tags: html, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

i want to load the route '/' first while running the app.js file of node.js,
as it is performing authentication and redirects to file index.html

As, the program is not able to find the index.html it gives me error.

So, i want to load the public folder after the authentication is done in app.js

```
app.use('/', passport.authenticate(WebAppStrategy.STRATEGY_NAME), function(req, res){

});
```

after then it should be redirected to index.html resided in public folder

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Set 'views' directory for any views 
// being rendered res.render()
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `next()`

```
app.use(passport.authenticate(WebAppStrategy.STRATEGY_NAME), function(req, res, next) {
    // do your authentication
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// Set 'views' directory for any views
// being rendered res.render()
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
```